# Game concept sketching

Tags: game-design

I am looking for 2D game concept sketching software(not engine). Something that will let me put sprites, backgrounds together and maybe do some minimal animations. The ultimate goal is to design game concept, to transfer something from your mind to visual representation with ease. So I can quickly look at those skethes and see if the concept worth something, show to others and then start development.
I work with photoshop, but it is not as productive as special software could be.

Comment: Which tech to use questions are considered off topic for the site. They are essentially an open ended poll, and don't have a correct answer. I suggest you search for this software on Google. You may want to use search terms like "[Storyboard software](http://www.studentfilmmakers.com/forums/showthread.php/115-Free-Storyboard-software)".

Answer (score 1):

I use Photoshop (GIMP is a free alternative) to do such that.

I use a combination of 2D images, background, pixel coordinate placement, and tile based movement using the "Align to Grid" function and have even done some animating in it.

I would definitely suggest using a 2D art program of some kind, even if not photoshop. You can do all kinds of things with online white boards, Maptools.net, Photoshop, MS Paint, or even printing out cutouts of 2D graphics and using paper IRL.

Comment: I doubly suggest Maptools actually. http://www.rptools.net/?page=maptool

Answer (score 0):

Paint.net! It's like photoshop, but it's free and much easier to use without tutorials

Comment: Hi there, Wes! This might be better suited as a comment.